# Google maps API v3 font issue

Tags: google-maps, fonts, shrink

I got a problem with the Google Maps API V3 on my site. 
On the page where the map is loaded, the font on my site shrink.

The images on the link below shows the difference. 
The first is on the page with Google Maps, the second is without.

Is this a known issue? And how to solve it?

image 1: http://bit.ly/N9uH1b
image 2: http://bit.ly/OA5etV

Answer (score 0):

Just answer for your question, if somebody, like me, will loose several hours for searching.
Add into your BODY tag the code:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased !important;
```

this is caused by CSS 3D transforms that Google Maps uses.